# Difference between structure pointer and structure when passed to function arg in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have following query:

THis is my structure in some .h file

```
typedef struct 
    {
        recUEInfo_t  *recUEInfoPtr_t;
        Int32   frameID;
        Int32   slotIndx;
        Int32   symNumber;

    }   recControlList;
```

If I do recControlList recControlListPtr; I can pass address to caller function
and collect it as a pointer in the definition

```
Fun(recControlListPtr);/* caller*/
```

and `void Fun(*recControlListPtr);/* actual func*/`

But if i do `recControlList     *recControlListPtr;` then what should I do to 
get the correct pointer?

Please help

Comment: Are you sure you copied/pasted the function declaration correctly? That doesn't look correct. Also, where is recControlListPtr defined?

Comment: Hi Firoze, its in next line under the shaded part

Comment: That's not a declaration or a definition. I'm asking where is recControlListPtr defined in the caller?

Comment: @op Just a tip, you're new to this (which is no problem), so you might not understand what is relevant/important information to someone trying to answer your question. Maybe instead of code fragments and single lines here and there (we don't even know whether these are in same files), you should show more complete code. Then someone can help you quickly I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I misunderstood who was the declarer and caller of the function initially, sorry about that, so if the function definition is:

```
Fun(recControlListPtr *precControlListPtr)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

You could call this way:

```
recControlListPtr rec1;
recContrlListPtr* prec2;
Fun(&rec1);
Fun(prec2);
```

Additional edit - My best guess at what I think you are trying to accomplish

```
typedef struct 
{
    recUEInfo_t  *recUEInfoPtr_t;
    int   frameID;
    int   slotIndx;
    int   symNumber;

}   recControlList;

void Fun(recControlList* pRecList)
{
    ASSERT(pRecList != NULL);
    int nFrameID = pRecList->frameID; // This line shows accessing the struct
    // Do other stuff
}

recControlList  rec1;
recControlList* pRec2 = &rec1;
Fun(&rec1);
Fun(pRec2);
```

Comment: THis is in case 1. What about case 2? Fun(**recControlListPtr); is correct? Can I get the actual structure values by this inside the Fun()?

Comment: Updated based on your comment. As far as getting the "structure" values, not sure what you are asking, where is the definition of recControlListPtr? You would need that information to know how to get at the data of the structure.